# What is the easiest and simplest way to bound $xy$

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof

Let $-1\le x\le 2$ and $-2\le y\le 3$. I have to bound $xy$. I can do it case by case. E.g

Case1
\begin{cases}
0\le -x\le 1\\
0\le -y\le2
\end{cases} Taking the product term by term yields $\boxed{0\le xy\le 2}$

Case2
\begin{cases}
0\le -x\le 1\\
0\le y\le3
\end{cases} Again I take the product to have $\boxed{-3\le xy\le0}$

Case3

\begin{cases}
0\le x\le 2\\
0\le -y\le2
\end{cases} then $\boxed{-4\le xy\le 0}$

Case 4

\begin{cases}
0\le x\le 2\\
0\le y\le3
\end{cases} then $\boxed{0\le xy\le6}$

Combining all these stuffs gives finally $-4\le xy\le 6$.

Does someone have an alternative method, more simpler and not as long as this thing above.

Comment: By the extreme value theorem, you note that the max and min values $xy$ can take are the extreme values of each interval. So, you only need to check 4 values.

Comment: @DonThousand If you use the extreme value theorem, you also have to check the origin, since both partial derivatives vanish there.

Comment: @GregMartin Oh I completely forgot about that. Good call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof without words:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is easy to see that the least value of the product $xy$ is either $-1×3$ or $-2×2.$ Similarly, the greatest value of this product in the rectangle is either $-1×-2$ or $2×3,$ so that we have $$-4\le xy\le 6.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x$ has a global negative minimum on interval of definition and $f(y)=y$ a global positive maximum on interval of definition and $f(x)=x$ has a global positive maximum on interval of definition and $f(y)=y$ a global negative minimum on interval of definition and both $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$ are strictly monotone.

Global minimum of $xy$ on that rectangle is then lesser of the product of those two pairs of values.

Similarly for global maximum of $xy$ on that rectangle.